# Way to remove parent and preserve children jq

Tags: jq

I have this input json as example:

**INPUT**

```
{
  "service1": {
    "action1": [
      "example1"
    ],
    "action2": [
      "example2",
      "example3",
      "example4"
    ]
    },
  "service2": {
    "action3": [
      "example5"
    ],
    "action4": [
      "example6",
      "example7",
      "example8"
    ]
    }
}
```

I need to remove parents: action1, action2, action3, action4 and preserve their children as join, is there a way to do that in jq ?

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
{
  "service1": [
      "example1",
      "example2",
      "example3",
      "example4"
    ],
  "service2": [
      "example5",
      "example6",
      "example7",
      "example8"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jq '.[] |= add'
```

Will generate

```json
{
  "service1": [
    "example1",
    "example2",
    "example3",
    "example4"
  ],
  "service2": [
    "example5",
    "example6",
    "example7",
    "example8"
  ]
}
```

As you can try in this [only demo](https://jqplay.org/s/oGdL6lb9Sz)

---

For `add`, please take a look at [jq's documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example33).